# vb.net textfile split by line to combobox

Tags: vb.net, split, text-files

vb.net textfile split by line  to combobox

```
test
cool
username: username1
username: username2
username: username3
username: username4
username: username5
test
```

I want to extract all 5 username in add combobox

Comment: I have edited my answer (see the bottom) for a pattern which matches both `username:` and `user name:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the lines into an array, and then use a `Regex` to match the username lines.

Start with putting:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

in the top of your code file, then you can use this code:

```
Dim FileLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("path to file") 'Read all the lines of the file into a String array.

Dim RgEx As New Regex("(?<=username\:\s).+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 'Declare a new, case-insensitive Regex.
For Each Line As String In FileLines 'Loop through every line.
    Dim m As Match = RgEx.Match(Line) 'Match the Regex pattern.
    If m IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.Success = True Then 'Have we found a match?
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(m.Value) 'Add the match to the ComboBox.
    End If
Next
```

The `Regex` is a class which is capable of matching substrings according to the specified pattern.

The pattern I used can be explained like this:

`(?<=username\:\s).+`

`(?<=username\:`: Match a line starting with `username:`.

`\s`: Match a space character (after `username:`).

`.+`: Match any character combination after that (which is your username, and what will be returned from `m.Value`).

---

**Online code test:** http://ideone.com/xnVkCc

**Read more about Regex:** [MSDN - .NET Framework Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/hs600312(v=vs.100).aspx)

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to match **both** `username:` and `user name:` you could try declaring the `Regex` with the following pattern instead:

```
Dim RgEx As New Regex("(?<=user(?:\s)?name\:\s).+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```